# How to get Complete image file path before upload using HTML or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

How can i get image file path before upload it somemthing like 
C:\Users\Punisher\Pictures\img2.jpg by using HTML, PHP or CSS

Comment: You can't get the full path. you will get fake path for ex: c:\fakepath\filename

Comment: you cant get that. And after upload, it will upload to some "tmp" directory

Answer (score 0):

#### 1: If you have a php script and images directory in the same path like:

```
| -- project
     --- images/pic.jpg
     --- path.php

<?php
    $path = sprintf("%s/%s", __DIR__, 'images/pic.jpg');
    echo $path;
?>
```

#### 2: The directory where php get the uploaded file is usually /tmp/tmpfilename in linux, and it can be configured in php.ini by setting:

```
upload_tmp_dir=/path/dir
```

Let say the html file input has name fileToUpload then PHP gets this file using the following (note tmp_name is fixed):

$tmpFileName = $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];

Then you can move it to your desired directory lets say /images like:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], '/images/'. $target_file);
```